# fill JComboBox with items from a multidimensional table

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, nullpointerexception, jcombobox

I'm trying to fill a JCombobox from items in a multidimensional table.
the items I trying to ad are the names of cities in that table.
this is my code :

```
String t21[][] = {{"Azores","Alaska","Pacific Time US & Canada","Chihuahua, La Paz, Mazatlan - New","Guadalajara, Mexico City, Monterrey - New","Bogota, Lima, Quito, Rio Branco","Atlantic Time","CasaBlanca GMT","Amsterdam, Berlin, Bern, Rome, Stockholm, Vienna","Athens, Bucharest, Istanbul","Moscow, St. Petersburg, Volgograd","Abu Dhabi, Muscat","Chennai, Kolkata, Mumbai, New Delh","Almaty, Novosibirsk","Bangkok, Hanoi, Jakarta","Beijing, Chongqing, Hong Kong, Urumqi","Osaka, Sapporo, Tokyo","Canberra, Melbourne, Sydney","",""},
        {"-6","-5","-4","-3","-2","-1","0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10"}};
for( int i = 0; i< t21.length-1; i++){
                   jComboBox1.addItem(t21[0][i]);
               }
```

but when I run my program I get this error :

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
>     at temps.interfac$2.run(interfac.java:125)  at
>   java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:251)     at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:727)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)   at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:688)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:686)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
>     at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:697)   at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)

Comment: Which line of code is line 125 of the interfac class? The exception tells us to look at this line: interfac.java:125

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels `jComboBox1.addItem(t21[0][i]);`

Comment: The error message then tells you exactly what is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Your error is telling you that the jComboBox1 variable is null.

Solution: initialize the variable first before using it.

---

Edit:
You state:

> the variable is already initialized, because I created a JComboBox in the design side using NetBeans

Don't take my word on it, and don't trust your assumptions. Use your program to test this to see what is in fact truly going on at this point in your code. Change your code to look like so:

```
System.out.println("is jComboBox1 null: " + (jComboBox1 == null)); // *** added *
for( int i = 0; i< t21.length-1; i++){
   jComboBox1.addItem(t21[0][i]);
}
```

And then please report back to us to see what the JVM tells you.

Comment: the variable is already initialized, because I created a JComboBox in the design side using NetBeans

Comment: @MohamedMed: please see edit to my answer above.

Comment: +1 for encouraging closer study. Once `jComboBox1` is initialized, an interesting anomaly arises due to the value of `t21.length-1`. As long as one is using an IDE, I've found it valuable to examine known errors in the debugger to get a sense for the unknown ones.

Comment: @trashgod: I have a gut feeling that you should write an answer to this question, that you have a deeper insight that should be shared with all.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels: I've tried to elaborate [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16182638/230513); don't hesitate to edit the answer _pro re nata_.

Answer (score 2):

Once `jComboBox1` is initialized, as suggested by @Hovercraft Full Of Eels, a new problem surfaces: Only a single entry appears in the combo. Examine the value of the loop limit to see why:

```
System.out.println(t21.length-1);
```

Suppose you want the combo to show the elements of the first *row*, a [*for-each*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html) loop may be more reliable:

```
for (String s : t21[0]) {
     jComboBox1.addItem(s);
}
```

See also [*Arrays*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html).